# Why not accrues?

Tags: grammar, literature

From [*Emma* by Jane Austen](http://www.austen.com/emma/vol2ch11.htm):

> It may be possible to do without dancing entirely. Instances have been known of young people passing many, many months successively without being at any ball of any description, and no material injury **accrue** either to body or mind; but when a beginning is made--when the felicities of rapid motion have once been, though slightly, felt--it must be a very heavy set that does not ask for more.

Why did she write *accrue* and not *accrues*?

Comment: Read it as *"...and **having** no material injury accrue"*, where that "deleted" participle mirrors *"young people **passing** many months"*. We probably wouldn't delete that word in that position today, but we wouldn't normally write sentences remotely like that anyway.

Comment: @FumbleFingers using *having* in such way would required a past participle then. Am I missing that?

Comment: @username901345: Jane Austen "made a stupid mistake"? Definitely *not!* I mean that 200 years ago it would have been more "normal" to simply remove the word ***having*** in that exact context. Probably because readers were expected to be more attentive and to follow lengthy convoluted structures more exactly - so they'd recognise and transparently understand the parallel structure of ***passing/having***, even when the [deleted](http://grammar.about.com/od/tz/g/Vp-Deletion.htm)  second word wasn't actually the same as the earlier one which it echoed.

Comment: @Maulik: The past participle would be appropriate if the "underlying" structure had been *"...and no material injury **having accrued**"*. But that's *not* the case here, since such a structure would clash with the earlier clause involving ***people passing many months*** (which is what the clause being looked at "mirrors/expands on".

Comment: @username901345: I don't recall a line like that in Shakespeare, but I suppose you mean there's a deleted ***that*** before ***hath*** there. That's a different kind of deletion, since it doesn't depend on any parallel structure involving an earlier instance of the deleted word (or in the case under consideration, an earlier word having a similar syntactic function).

Comment: @username901345: There are only two sentences in your citation. If you're asking what that final 13-word clause means, be warned that ***set*** is usually one of the longest entries in a dictionary. The overall sense is *anyone except a really heavy/serious person would want more [dancing]*, but I'm not sure what if any word Austen could reasonably have substituted for ***set*** there. Today you could substitute ***mindset*** and be at least *close* to the original intended sense, but that may not have been exactly what the author meant.

Comment: Having been exposed to only a diminutive amount of works of giants of English literature, and with ignorable apprehension of English, in the manner of speaking, my simplistic mind understands this *"no material injury accrue either to body or mind"* as English subjunctive.

Comment: @DamkerngT. I am afraid that your false modesty has falsified your intent. "in A manner of speaking" is correct; not "THE."

Comment: +1. I'd actually have expected *accruing* ("of young people passing [...], and no material injury accruing [...]"), but either way, bare *accrue* seems odd.

Comment: @FumbleFingers *Set* here describes a physique: [*OED 1*](http://archive.org/stream/oed8barch#page/n537/mode/2up), *s.v.* **Set**, **14.** gives “The build or make of a person. *Obs*. exc. *dial*.” We still say *heavy-set* in the same sense, although there it's probably the participle of the corresponding sense of the verb.

Answer (score 1):

This is wild speculation on my part, but I'm thinking that *accrue* could be in the subjunctive mood, and that's why there is no *s* on the end of it. Jane Austen is expressing the outlandish hypothetical idea (tongue-in-cheek of course) that young people can go without dancing without—amazingly—suffering harm. Maybe that absurdity could be expressed with the subjunctive.

Our use of the subjunctive mood is much more limited these days. I think they used to use it a lot more in her day, and perhaps this is an instance of it.

(Another possibility is that she simply made a mistake and no one has noticed it until now. Crazier things have happened.)

Comment: I think you're right about the subjunctive. I would only add that Latin will very often have that type of subjunctive in subordinate clauses, and many academic books at the time of Jane Austen's writing were either written in, or influenced heavily by, Latin. Austen might be comically adopting a Latin-sounding syntax in a mock-scholarly tone.

Comment: +1 I'm inclined to agree with you: this is a "subjunctive of result."